# Storing pointers to elements of a dynamic array

Tags: c++

I have two arrays where the first one consists of integers and the other one consists of structs, with one member being a pointer to a given element in the first array.

```
struct A {
   ...
   int *ptr;
};

int arr[100];
vector<A>arr2;

void AddElementAndAssignPointer(int index) {
    arr2.push_back({...});
    arr2.ptr = &arr[index];
}
```

Now the limitation with this approach is that the size of the first array is static, and I would like it to be dynamic. However if I were to make it a std::vector, the references to the elements in that array would be lost when the vector is resized and the contents are copied into larger array.

What are the possible solutions to this problem?

Edit: The problem is how do I store references to elements of an array and have it be dynamic at the same time.

Edit 2:  I'm creating a half edge mesh structure. The first array consists of vertices of the mesh. The second array consists of edges of the mesh. To simplify the problem a bit I need to have pointer to a vertex for each edge. Vertex array needs to be dynamic as new vertices are added by the user.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve. This is probably not the solution.

Comment: Thats the problem you are having with your solution. Why do you want to have references to the array, what are you trying to do with this data structure you are building?

Comment: Instead of `std::vector`, use `std::list`.  Then you don't worry about invalidation.  Of course, this may only cover-up what you're really trying to solve.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for the suggestion! I just added a comment about what my actual problem is. Do you think `std::list` would work?

Comment: The `std::list` will "work", the problem is if you expect `std::list` to do the same as `std::vector`, since it is not a random access container.  For example, you can't use `[ ]` to access elements.  Instead you have to use `std::advance` to get to the element in question.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That makes sense, thanks! I'll try `std::list` out. I guess there's otherwise not a general solution to the problem I defined from the start. Maybe I should close the question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the standard solution is to, instead of storing an actual pointer or anything (because those can move around as the `vector` is resized), storing both a reference to the vector and a `size_t` for the index into the vector.

Comment: Unfortunately storing indices is not option. For the specific problem I need to store pointers.

Comment: Also storing indexes is not really a great way to move it around. As the vector and it's index could get mixed with other stuff. The best solution would be a `std::list` and passing iterators to it's elements around

Comment: @LennyWhite What part of the design makes you need a pointer?

Comment: @TarickWelling Then the correct answer would be to create a `struct` that can hold the vector reference and the index, perhaps with helper methods. An `std::list` has a lot of other issues that could cause problems, especially in practice instead of theory; for example, they are cache-unfriendly so slow to iterate over.

Comment: Yeah you are right linked lists will not be very fast to iterate over... But using the index approach (or struct) on the first glance looks like it would be a nightmare to make sense of. Since with my specific problem I need to use multiple pointers between vertices, edges and faces. And also all the implementations of this data structure use pointers.

Comment: What other problems do linked lists have in practice?

Comment: I mostly mean various performance issues, sorry for the confusion. No random access, slower to iterate over in practice even though that’s O(n) for both, cache unfriendly, etc. And I think `template <typename T> struct StableVectorIterator { std::vector<T> const& vec; typename std::vector<T>::size_type index;}` along with `operator*`, `operator++`, etc. would help; I’m surprised I can’t find something like that already in Boost.